# Real canonical form, rank, signature

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the real canonical form, rank and signature of the quadratic form q(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + 2xz + 4yz + 3z^2 ?

Answer (score 2):

$$
q(x,y,z)=(x+z)^2+(y+2z)^2-2z^2
$$